# Grabbing the value of a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I am having issues trying to get the value of the button. Currently it will call the button I click but says the value is undefined. I have attempted to use *this* and experimented with JQuery's val(). I would prefer the answer be in vanilla JavaScript if possible.

The relevant code is as follows.

```js
var grabButton = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function checkLetter()
{
    // Pull the value of the button and declare it as letter
    letter = this.grabButton.value;
    console.log(letter);
}

grabButton.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() { checkLetter() });
});
```

```html
<div id="letters">
        <button class="letter" value="A">A</button>
        <button class="letter" value="B">B</button>
        <button class="letter" value="C">C</button>
        <button class="letter" value="D">D</button>
        <button class="letter" value="E">E</button>
        <button class="letter" value="F">F</button>
        <button class="letter" value="G">G</button>
        <button class="letter" value="H">H</button>
        <button class="letter" value="I">I</button>
        <button class="letter" value="J">J</button>
        <button class="letter" value="K">K</button>
        <button class="letter" value="L">L</button>
        <button class="letter" value="M">M</button>
        <button class="letter" value="N">N</button>
        <button class="letter" value="O">O</button>
        <button class="letter" value="P">P</button>
        <button class="letter" value="Q">Q</button>
        <button class="letter" value="R">R</button>
        <button class="letter" value="S">S</button>
        <button class="letter" value="T">T</button>
        <button class="letter" value="U">U</button>
        <button class="letter" value="V">V</button>
        <button class="letter" value="W">W</button>
        <button class="letter" value="X">X</button>
        <button class="letter" value="Y">Y</button>
        <button class="letter" value="Z">Z</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: `checkLetter` cannot determine which button was clicked or which value that has, because your event handler does pass nothing to `checkLetter()` (and doesn't call it with the element as the `this` argument either). Use just `button.addEventListener("click", checkLetter);` instead of `function() { checkLetter() }` and you will be able to use `this` as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const grabButton = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function checkLetter() {
  const letter = this.value;
  console.log(letter);
}

grabButton.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", checkLetter));
```

```html
<div id="letters">
  <button class="letter" value="A">A</button>
  <button class="letter" value="B">B</button>
  <button class="letter" value="C">C</button>
  <button class="letter" value="D">D</button>
  <button class="letter" value="E">E</button>
  <button class="letter" value="F">F</button>
  <button class="letter" value="G">G</button>
  <button class="letter" value="H">H</button>
  <button class="letter" value="I">I</button>
  <button class="letter" value="J">J</button>
  <button class="letter" value="K">K</button>
  <button class="letter" value="L">L</button>
  <button class="letter" value="M">M</button>
  <button class="letter" value="N">N</button>
  <button class="letter" value="O">O</button>
  <button class="letter" value="P">P</button>
  <button class="letter" value="Q">Q</button>
  <button class="letter" value="R">R</button>
  <button class="letter" value="S">S</button>
  <button class="letter" value="T">T</button>
  <button class="letter" value="U">U</button>
  <button class="letter" value="V">V</button>
  <button class="letter" value="W">W</button>
  <button class="letter" value="X">X</button>
  <button class="letter" value="Y">Y</button>
  <button class="letter" value="Z">Z</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this solution and it returns "undefined" in the console.

Comment: @Fikrys Try the 'Run code snippet'. It's working :)

Comment: @LarsFlieger That's so odd.. on my IDE it isn't working. I'll play around with it. Thank you. (edit) Ah! It was the change to a const oddly enough. It was originally declared as a var outside the function.